# Is it correct to say "I became interested in programming"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

If I want to tell someone that "I became interested in programming". is it correct? But it doesn't seem to be correct?

My doubt: *Became interested* does't sound good. It should be something else.

Became--2nd form.
Interested--2nd form.

Please clear my doubt?

Comment: What is the context?  Is this for a resume or CV, or just casual conversation?  Or are you asking whether the grammar of this sentence is OK?

Comment: There is no special context, just I was asking for the sake of grammar & wanted to know how can I say it more effectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase is perfectly acceptable, just finish the sentence now:

"I became interested in programming" back in high school.

"I became interested in programming" the first time I saw a video game.

"I became interested in programming" when I saw a group of boys make the teletype do something interesting.